# Don't understand why this generating function needs to be taken to the power $-1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions, functional-equations

I'm given the following recursive formula for a sequence:

$u_{n+1}=u_n+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}u_ku_{n-k}\ (n\ge1),\ u_0=0,\ u_1=1$

Since $u_0=0$ we can rewrite:

$u_{n+1}=u_n+\sum_{k=0}^{n}u_ku_{n-k},\ (n\ge1)$

now writing $u(x)=u_1x+u_2x^2+....$ we obtain (by multiplying by $x^{n+1}$ and summing):

$u(x)-x=xu(x)+xu(x)^2$

Which I believe we can just solve using

$xu(x)^2+(x-1)u(x)+x=0$

So

$u(x)=\frac{1-x\pm\sqrt{(x-1)^2-4x^2}}{2x}$

However, my book says the solution should be

$u(x)=\frac{2x}{1-x+\sqrt{1-2x-3x^2}}$

Which is my answer to the power $-1$. I don't see why this is necessary, so any hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: Multiply your result by the conjugate of denominator and simplify. Expand what is inside the radical.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Ah thanks, yea I feel pretty dumb right now:p.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Good observation, but I still wonder why the book put the answer in the form it did.

Comment: @DavidK. I totally agree. What thr OP wrote is much better.

Comment: @user2520938. You are much better than the book. So, $+1$

Comment: I think I can see where the book is coming from.  The form of the answer given in the book is _evidently_ a power series, while this is not true of the form given by the OP, since power series are not in general closed under division by $x$.